# javafx mouse events in transparent image

Tags: javafx

JavaFx ImageView doesn't trigger Mouse Events such as press or drag if you click or drag on a transparent pixel, is there anyway to work around this and detect mouse events from transparent areas ?

I have this image [image]

that i added into this very simple JavaFX scene [image]

using an ImageView named view and i want to move it with Mouse Drag events
so i wrote this code

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{

    double initMx, initMy,initX, initY;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage ps) throws Exception {
        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        Image im = new Image("0.png");
        ImageView view = new ImageView(im);
        double fact = im.getWidth() / im.getHeight();

        view.setFitHeight(300);
        view.setFitWidth(300 * fact);

        view.setOnMousePressed(e->{
            initX = view.getTranslateX();
            initY = view.getTranslateY();
            initMx = e.getSceneX();
            initMy = e.getSceneY();
        });

        view.setOnMouseDragged(e->{
            double dx = initMx - e.getSceneX();
            double dy = initMy - e.getSceneY();

            double nx = initX - dx;
            double ny = initY - dy;

            view.setTranslateX(nx);
            view.setTranslateY(ny);

        });

        pane.getChildren().add(view);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 500);

        ps.setScene(scene);
        ps.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

this code works fine so far, 
but if you press or drag somewhere like under his ears ( or anywhere transparent ) nothing will happen ! how to fix this !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The more natural and easiest solution would have been to just set pick on bounds to true.

```
view.setPickOnBounds(true);
```

Comment: i didn't know what this method does before, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by setting this image as a graphic in a `Button` like so

```
button.setGraphics(new ImageView(im));
```

*Note: You will need to remove style from the button after adding the `ImageView` by setting the button background with a transparent background color*

Comment: @JavaNoob wondering why you decided to accept this hack when there's the straightforward solution suggested by (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51999089/203657)[mipa] - ahh ... just seeing that it is half a day newer than this ;)

Comment: I would say that mipa solution is better

Comment: indeed that's right ! i didn't see your answer and this one worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you didn't yet:

```
   view.setOnMouseDragged(e->{
        double dx = initMx - e.getX();
        double dy = initMy - e.getY();
```

Comment: thanks for trying to be helpful - but ... well, did you try it? The problem really is that transparent pixels are transparent to mouseEvents, that is the method is never called for parts of image that are outside the shape.